# Colour help, code snippet needs explaining

Tags: java, colors, rgb, code-snippets

Basically i was looking in to rendering sprtiesheets and this guy gave a tutorial where the spite sheet uses 4 colours: Black , Dark Grey , Light Grey and White.

These then correspond to a different colour through a method. E.g. black is green, white is red etc.

Anyway, i wanted to use 5 colours instead of 4 but i wanted to understand this as well as it wasnt explained.

The Code:

```
    public class Colours {


    public static int get(int colour1, int colour2, int colour3, int colour4, int colour5)      {
    return (get(colour4) << 24) + (get(colour3) << 16) + (get(colour2) << 8) + (get(colour1));
}

    private static int get(int colour)  {
        if(colour < 0)
            return 255;
    int r = colour / 100 % 10;
    int g = colour / 10 % 10;
    int b = colour % 10;
    return r * 36 + g * 6 + b;
}

static {
    Colours.get(555, 543, 542, 123);
}
```

Someone told me it had something to do with bases, basically i need to know whta the code means and how to get those colour numbers  e.g. 542 = aColour. What colour though

thanks

Comment: Ask the guy, who gave you this code snippet.

Comment: He's inactive, for like 3 months

Answer (score 0):

`get(int color)` Interprets a decimal number as base 6 and returns the corresponding integer, where each digit seems to stand for a color component in the range 0..5.

000 seems to stand for black, 555 for white, 500 for red, 50 for green, 5 for blue etc.

`get(int color1...)` packs four of those into a 32 bit integer. It is not possible to pack more than 4 x 8 bit into a 32 bit integer.